# Why doesn't pmwiki have an ID system like MediaWiki?

Tags: pmwiki

Every single site that runs on Mediawiki that I have ever visited has the option of replacing the title of an article with the following phrase in the url:?&curid=[any number]. For example: http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/?&curid=1999, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?&curid=2001

So, since PMWiki is wiki software like MediaWiki and has a url structure that is similar to Mediawiki, why don't pmwiki site urls have any kind of ID system?

Answer (score 0):

In PmWiki, page urls are deduced from page names themselves.
For example, the page MyGroup.MyPage may be reached via either:

- http://mywiki/?n=MyGroup.MyPage
- http://mywiki/MyGroup/MyPage

(according to wiki's [Clean Url](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/CleanUrls) configuration)

The [SQLite PageStore](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/SQLite) cookbook recipe (ie. PmWiki's addon), would provide shortened urls.

It also should be noted that page names could remain short, using `(:title ...:)` markup in the page itself to provide a more detailed title.